# Upload a Laravel 4.2 project on bytehost

Tags: laravel, web-hosting

I have uploaded my Laravel 4.2 project (using Filezilla) which is stored in folder name main-Laravel into the htdocs folder on bytehost.when I tried accessing it like this http://bcms.byethost8.com/main-laravel/public/, I an error saying Fatal error: **require(): Failed opening required '/home/vol12_4/byethost8.com/b8_16140412/htdocs/main-laravel/bootstrap/../../main-laravel/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/vol12_4/byethost8.com/b8_16140412/htdocs/main-laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17.** I did not have this problem when working on my local machine, so what can I do to resolve this problem and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do additional setup to get Laravel working on a shared hosting.

Laravel needs composer to get the autoloading right and few other requirements to be run (such as higher PHP version, several PHP extensions & so on).

Here you can find more info:
http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/setup-laravel-4-in-shared-hosting-with-securing-laravel-base-file